# Selecting feature from VectorTile in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, select-by-attribute, vector-tiles

I've problems with a selection of a feature from `VectorTile`. I've no problem with selection using `Vector`:

```js
  var vectortile_layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/ne/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0' +
          '&request=GetFeature&typeName=ne%3Ane_10m_admin_0_countries&outputFormat=application%2Fjson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    }),
  });
  map.addLayer(vectortile_layer);

  var highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255,0,255,1.0)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)',
      width: 2
    })
  });

  var selected = null;

  map.on('singleclick', function(e) {
    if (selected !== null) {
      selected.setStyle(undefined);
      selected = null;
    }

    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(f) {
      selected = f;
      f.setStyle(highlightStyle);
      return true;
    });

  });
```

But when I try to use a `VectorTile` with the code below:

```
  var vectortile_layer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
      format: new ol.format.MVT(),
      url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/' +
            'ne:ne_10m_admin_0_countries@EPSG%3A900913@pbf/{z}/{x}/{-y}.pbf'
    }),
  });
  map.addLayer(vectortile_layer);

  var highlightStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255,0,255,1.0)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)',
      width: 2
    })
  });

  var selected = null;

  map.on('singleclick', function(e) {
    if (selected !== null) {
      selected.setStyle(undefined);
      selected = null;
    }

    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(f) {
      selected = f;
      f.setStyle(highlightStyle);
      return true;
    });

  });
```

On click I see this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: f.setStyle is not a function

I'm using OpenLayers 6.3.1

Comment: For that code to work you would need to use `new ol.format.MVT({featureClass: ol.Feature}),`
(see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_MVT-MVT.html) as the default RenderFeature does not have a setStyle method.  Note that if a polygon is split between tiles you will only select one part of it, and only at one zoom level.  This example may be a better method https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-tile-selection.html

Comment: Thank you @Mike :)
If you add your comment as answer I can vote it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that code to work you would need to use `new ol.format.MVT({featureClass: ol.Feature}),` (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_format_MVT-MVT.html) as the default `RenderFeature` does not have a `setStyle` method. Note that if a polygon is split between tiles you will only select one part of it, and only at one zoom level. This example may be a better method https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-tile-selection.html

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to select features/polygons split between tiles as a whole? The only solution I came up with is to iterate through all features on layer and filtering those with the same business-id (set by us).